# Control PC from Android phone?

Tags: android, remote, remote-access

I always wanted to control my Linux PC via my smartphone, and found a way to do it. It's called CRC Remote. I could have several profiles with buttons, and on the press of one it would run the configured key press sequence. However, as I recently reinstalled Linux, I didn't have the program on my PC anymore. I then visited the homepage, just to find out that the page doesn't exist anymore. And I can't find the app in the Play Store. So I couldn't use it anymore. Are there any good alternatives that can send keystrokes to the PC? Because I was using it with many programs and didn't have to memorize all of the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I use connectbot on my phone to ssh into my Ubuntu boxes. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en_US&gl=US

Answer (score 0):

[KDE Connect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/) can do a lot of what you ask about. You may want to look into that.